# How to move waves(made with sine) from top of the picture to the bottom?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to draw waves onto the sea, but I got no idea how to moves those from top to bottom. No matter what I change, they stay at the top of the picture.
Here's the code I'm using to draw the waves:

```
Dimension d = getSize();
        int x, y, winWidth = d.width, winHeight = d.height;
        int halfHeight = 10;
        int lastX = 0, lastY = halfHeight;
        double trajectory = 2 * Math.PI;
        double factor = trajectory / 100;

        for (x = 1; x <= winWidth; x++) {
            double sine = Math.sin (x * factor) * halfHeight;
            y = halfHeight - (int)sine;
            graafika.drawLine (x, y, lastX, lastY);
            lastX = x; lastY = y;
        }
```

Here's a picture, how it looks at the moment.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can we have the complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use height?

```
graafika.drawLine (x, y+winHeight-20, lastX, lastY+winHeight-20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just "mirror" the placement of the wave by replacing

```
y = halfHeight - (int)sine;
```

with

```
y = winHeight - (halfHeight - (int)sine);
```

This first places your sine wave at the very bottom, then moving it up a half sine wave, allowing the whole wave to be visible.